# what is word vector dimension

Tags: vector, neural-network

I am currently an amateur in deep learning and was reading about word2vector on this site
https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-3-more-fun-with-word-vectors

For either CBOW or skipgram model, I can see that the dimension of the word vectors is 300 and the vocabulary size is 15000. What I have read in the earlier post, is that we can one hard encode the words in vectors. So I guess the word vector dimension should be equal to the vocabulary size or to put the question in a different way, what is this word dimension and how to do visualize it. How do you take this dimension?

Comment: Can you please explain this sentence: "we one hot code the word vectors"?

Answer (score 5):

"Word Vector Dimension" is the dimension of the vector that you have trained with the training document. Technically you can choose any dimension, like 10, 100, 300, even 1000. Industry norm is 300-500 because we have experimented with different dimensions (300, 400, 500, ... 1000, etc.) but haven't noticed the significant performance improvement after 300-400. (This also depends on your training data.) As it sounds, more dimension means heavier computation. However, if we set the dimension too low, then there is not much vector space to capture the information that the entire training document contains.

How to visualize it?

You can't easily visualize 300-dimensional vector and probably visualizing 300-d vectors isn't too useful to you. What we can do is to project those vectors to 2-d space, the space that we are most familiar with and that we can understand easily.

Your last statement **So I guess the word vector dimension should be equal to the vocabulary size** is WRONG!
Vocab size is 171,476 words (total # of words in English)! Word vector dimension (mostly 300-500. You don't want to train 1-billion-dimensional vectors, do you?) is the size of vector you decide in advance to train the data. My video (shameless plug) will help you to understand the important word vector concepts: [AI with the Best](https://youtu.be/kGGA1Wm8_x0)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the word vector dimension does not reflect the vocabulary size. 
What Word2Vec is doing is mapping the words to their representation in a vector space and you can make this space of any dimension you want: : Each word is represented by a point in this space and word vector dimension are the coordinates of this word in this space.
Also words that tend to appear in the same context appear next to each other in this space.

Hope this helps

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-3-more-fun-with-word-vectors Please have a look at this link and let me know what does "Setting the minimum word count to 40 gave us a total vocabulary of 16,492 words with 300 features apiece" means with 300 features. what are features of the words